# Changing Magento domain breaks URL rewrites

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm just launching my first Magento store (on CentOS & Apache) and I've switched over from my setup subdomain - http://prelive.mydomain.com (where everything worked fine, with url rewriting enabled & working) - to the live subdomain http://www.mydomain.com, basically just by doing the following:

1. clearing caches via the admin interface
2. updating the secure & unsecure base urls in the db

   - UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
   - UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'https://www.mydomain.co.uk/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
3. moving the entire site file system from /var/www/html/prelive to /var/www/html/www (I tried copying but it caused all sorts of permission problems which I'll figure out later!)
4. manually editing the media base path in var/resource_config.json
5. updating my virtual host like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
       ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
       ServerAlias www.mydomain.co.uk
       ErrorLog logs/www.mydomain.co.uk-error_log
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. editing the base .htaccess file like this ()

   ```
   SetEnvIf Host www\.mydomain.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=angling_r_en
   SetEnvIf Host www\.mydomain.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
   SetEnvIf Host ^mydomain.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=angling_r_en
   SetEnvIf Host ^.mydomain.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
   ```

And it almost works... but the url rewriting is broken.  I can see the site on http://www.mydomain.com but navigating to subpages gets a 404 (e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/path/to/product.html ), unless I specifically alter the URL to point through index.php like this http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/path/to/product.html or http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin

For reference, in .htaccess I also have (left unchanged during the switch of subdomain):

```
RewriteBase /
```

and

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Any thoughts on what I forgot?

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to reindex the catalog URL rewrites to incorporate your new URL changes! See `System > Index Management` and reindex the Catalog URL Rewrites.

Comment: Thanks Yrcrz - makes sense (I think I rebuilt them all already...) - when I do the admin interface _says_ `"Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt."` but it makes no difference.  Do you know where those are stored?  Maybe it isn't actually rebuilding them...?

Comment: I should also have said it is an Apache 404 page I am seeing, on every page in the site except the homepage.  Its like mod_rewrite just stopped working, but why!!?? :[

Comment: Just to confirm, if I turn off "Use Web Server Rewrites" in System > Config > Web > Search Engines Optimization everything works  perfectly... its just the rewrites that are bust.

Comment: Also tried truncating core_url_rewrite table then rebuilding "Catalog URL Rewrites", table was re-populated, but made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so the problem was on the server all along, not Magento...

Basically rewrites weren't working because I needed this in both my VirtualHost container in both both httpd.conf and ssl.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/www>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

What I still don't understand is how it worked on the old location (which definitely didn't have this) and not the new one... but it works just the same as before now, with "Use Web Server Rewrites" turned on in System > Configuration > Web, creating "clean" urls which are rewritten through index.php by mod_rewrite.